# Is this a valid differences-in-differences-in-differences design?

Tags: regression, econometrics, difference-in-difference

I'm interesting in exploiting policy changes in benefits enjoyed by individuals to estimate the effect of the benefit on a certain outcome variable. The policy changes come in the following form:

- at T0, recipients of system A exist
- at T1, a new system B is introduced, where the benefits are calculated differently.

Both systems, A and B, exists concurrently. Meaning that **noone transfers from A to B**.

Furthermore, members of system B living in cities C receive increased benefits, whereas members of system B living in cities D do not. No geographical variation exists for members of system A.

Therefore, the size of the benefit depends on 1. which system one belongs to (A or B) 2. if in system B, whether an individual belongs to cities of groups C or D. I want to exploit the variation in these benefits to estimate its effect on Y.

A colleague suggested the following differences-in-differences-in-differences design, but I'm unsure if it is a valid one:

- dB is a binary indicator for system B recipients
- dC is a binary indicator for living in cities of group C
- dT is a binary indicator for the post-treatment period (T1 and beyond)

Y = b0 + b1dC + b2dB + b3dC X dB + b4dT + b5dT X dC + b6dT X dB + b7dT X dB X dC

The coefficient of interest is then b7, which estimates the effect of variation in time, system and location on outcome Y. However, I suspect this is not a valid design. Decomposing the estimate of this coefficient:

*b7_hat = 
(difference in mean outcome between system B recipients in cities C in period 2 and the same group in period 1) -
(difference in mean outcome between system B recipients in cities D in period 2 and the same group in period 1) -
(difference in mean outcome between system A recipients in cities C in period 2 and the same group in period 1)*

However, the problem here is that system B recipients do not exist in period 1. In other words, the estimate would simplify to:

*b7_hat = 
(mean outcome between system B recipients in cities C in period 2) -
(mean outcome between system B recipients in cities D in period 2) -
(difference in mean outcome between system A recipients in cities C in period 2 and the same group in period 1)*

In other words, I only observe the pre-treatment outcome for recipients in system A. I am completely lost in how I need to reformulate this setup to go about it correctly, so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does system B do anything for recipients in cities D? And is every recipient of system B also a recipient of system A, and vice versa, in both types of cities?

Comment: @pythonuser, system B entails a different calculation of the benefits for all recipients, but only those in cities D are treated with an increased benefit (10% increase). In other words, the calculation of the benefit is different compared to system A, and system B recipients receive a 10% increase in cities C. 

You cannot be both a system A and a system B recipient: they're mutually exclusive.

Comment: If you don't have pre-treatment observations for system B recipients, then you cannot use diff-in-diff at the individual level. You may want to look at city-level outcomes instead.